# How to check for equality element-wise for two vectors?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have two vectors that I need to check element wise for equality and return the total number of elements that are equal. So comparing a = {1,0,1} and b = {1,0,0} would return 2.

The example below is an effort I've made of a recursive function, but is returning errors.

```
Elementcompare[list1_, list2_] :=   If[First[list1] == First[list2], 1, 0]  + Elementcompare[Rest[list1], Rest[list2]];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume length of vectors is the same in general. There is a function for this - [**HammingDistance**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HammingDistance.html) you can use it to define:

```
elcom[a_List, b_List] := Length[a] - HammingDistance[a, b]
```

Test it out

```
elcom[a, b]
```

> 2

Also check out [**EditDistance**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EditDistance.html) .

Answer (score 2):

An easy and fast method is to use vector-level numeric operations.

```
a = {0, 1, 0, 1, 2};

b = {2, 1, 3, 1, 2};

a - b
```

> ```
> {-2, 0, -3, 0, 0}
> ```

```
Unitize[a - b]
```

> ```
> {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}
> ```

```
Tr @ Unitize[a - b]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

This is equivalent to `HammingDistance` in this use:

```
HammingDistance[a, b]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

I use `Tr` to sum because it is very fast on packed arrays.  Speed comparison with `HammingDistance` on version 7 with two long lists:

```
a = RandomInteger[3, 500000];
b = RandomInteger[3, 500000];

Do[HammingDistance[a, b], {50}] // Timing // First

Do[Tr @ Unitize[a - b], {50}]   // Timing // First

0.968

0.171
```

Performance is more similar when `a` and `b` are not packed arrays but the numeric method still wins.  You can subtract the returned value from `Length[a]` to get your target metric just as Vitaliy showed.

Answer (score 2):

If your vectors are bit-vectors (0s and 1s), you can squeeze more speed out of this computation by using bit operators:

```
a = RandomInteger[1, 500000];

b = RandomInteger[1, 500000];
```

First, check for consistency:

```
HammingDistance[a, b]
```

> 249965

```
Tr@Unitize[a - b]
```

> 249965

```
Total@BitXor[a, b]
```

> 249965

Check for speed:

```
Do[HammingDistance[a, b], {50}] // Timing // First
```

> 1.98993

```
Do[Tr@Unitize[a - b], {50}] // Timing // First
```

> 0.437551

```
Do[Total@BitXor[a, b], {50}] // Timing // First
```

> 0.139816